# diffrent results when trying to find length of an array using pointer arithmetic inside a function and inside of main

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion

for some odd reason when I run this code:

```
int func(int arr[],int n) {
    int a = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

I get an address,

and when I run the same code inside main I get the length of the array.

any idea why?

I ran it inside main and it gave me the length of an array, and when I ran it inside a function it gave me an address.

Comment: When declared as an argument, `int arr[]` is the same as `int *arr`. So `&arr` is a pointer to a pointer (type `int **`). You then dereference it to get a pointer (of type `int *`). Once your array have *decayed* to a pointer, you can't use tricks like that (or `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` which is even more common) to get the size of the array.

Comment: You may want to read this: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) Note, however, that some of the information there only applies to C++, not C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function declaration

```
int func(int arr[],int n){
```

is adjusted by the compiler to

```
int func(int *arr,int n){
```

On the other hand. the array passed to the function as an argument expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `int *`.

So within the function you actually deal with a pointer instead of an array.

In any case the expression with pointers used in this line within the function

```
int a = *(&arr + 1) - arr;
```

is invalid and invokes undefined behavior.